# Best way to Stop a PowerShell Script or to re-ask the Right-Host

Tags: powershell, prompt

Here is my code. It feels really dirty and I have I have a long list of Right-Host Questions I'll be asking.

I'm wanting to stop the script if a Null, Blank, or otherwise empty (including just adding a space) entry is added. Right now I've got it to stop, but was hoping there was a cleaner way to group the "If" statements and perhaps to re-ask the question if any of the aforementioned entries happen...

```
$Parent = Read-Host -prompt "Enter full parent path that will contain the new folder"
if ( $Parent -eq $null)
  {
    Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
    Exit
  }
if ( $Parent -eq "")
  {
    Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
    Exit
  }
if ( $Parent -eq " ")
  {
    Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
    Exit
  }
else 
  {
    Write-Host "You Entered $Parent"
  }

$Name = Read-Host -prompt "Enter Folder Name"
if ( $Name -eq $null)
  {
    Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
    Exit
  }
if ( $Name -eq "")
  {
    Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
    Exit
  }
if ( $Name -eq " ")
  {
    Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
    Exit
  }
else 
  {
    Write-Host "You Entered $Name"
  }
```

Comment: You would be much better off using the parameter validation features built right into PowerShell.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=notnullorempty+powershell

Comment: Your Bing search was not helpful. I know how to search for something on the internet, but what I was finding was confusing as I'm VERY new to PowerShell. That is why I asked the question here.

Comment: Bill, I was trying the notnull param, but I was wanting it to also look for a space as well. In that case it isn't null.

Comment: @Shane - I would disagree as Jaqueline's results come up with a significant number of very basic, and helpful, recommendations for someone who is just beginning to learn about functions, loops, and variable assignment validation, which it appears you are.  You're also wanting to account for 'numerous possibilities,' which means you need to make a full list of requirements for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gravity - I understand that. What I was saying was that I had already searched. Putting in a Bing search string is sort of passive-aggressive. I'm sure you get a lot of folks around here that don't search before asking questions, but in my case that wasn't true. I used Google and not Bing, however I've already visited a lot of the search results that Jaqueline had sent. As far as numerous possibilities: please re-read the question I asked. I specifically stated what I wanted to stop the script on.

Comment: You will be better off learning how PowerShell's parameter validation works rather than trying to write your own. Done correctly, PowerShell can prompt for missing parameters or even lists. Prompting for input, in most cases, is not recommended because it won't work in a non-interactive fashion.

Comment: I agree, and I'm working on that separately. In this instance I want my user to input all of the data manually. I'm sure I can do that with Params, but I'm not quite ready to go that route just yet. This is to help move things forward a little bit more in my IT department vs having to teach them how to use powershell (that MIGHT come later). As it is I'm giving myself a crash-course to take some pressure off of my techs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put validation conditions together like that :

```
$Parent = Read-Host -prompt "Enter full parent path that will contain the new folder"

 if ( ($Parent -eq $null) -or ($Parent -eq "") -or ($Parent -eq " "))
  {
Write-Host "You entered a blank value: This Script is now Exiting."
  }
else 
  {
Write-Host "You Entered $Parent"
  }
```

You can either make that a function with a mandatory non null parameter(as bill said much better/easier on the long run), or make a while loop until the input is right.

Comment: That makes sense, but what is the best way to loop back to the question instead of using the Exit command and having the user start over?

Comment: There is no best way yet, it mostly depends where you go with your script (maybe not a loop but just mandatory parameter). But as gravity mentionned, I strongly recommand reading through the results of Jacqueline's link. It can feel like it make sense to do it that way now but once you'll handle powershell parameters validation, you'll hate even thinking doing it another way.